# track changes in table row after update using trigger and to write changed column name and value to another table

Tags: mysql

i am writing a trigger for record changes in the table while updating 
my trigger is

```
CREATE TRIGGER vehicle_mst_log 
AFTER UPDATE ON vehicle_mst
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    IF (OLD.COLUMN1 != NEW.COLUMN1) THEN
        INSERT INTO ABN_OLDLOGTABLE (
            TABLENAME,
            COLUMNNAME,
            OLDVALUE,
            NEWVALUEW,
            TIME,
            USER)
        VALUES (
            "TABLE",
            "COLUMN1",
            COLUMN1OLDVALUE,
            COLUMN1NEWVALUE,
            NOW(),
            USER);
    END IF;
    IF (OLD.COLUMN2 != NEW.COLUMN2) THEN
        INSERT INTO ABN_OLDLOGTABLE (
            TABLENAME,
            COLUMNNAME,
            OLDVALUE,
            NEWVALUEW,
            TIME,
            USER)
        VALUES (
            "TABLE",
            "COLUMN2",
            COLUMN2OLDVALUE,
            COLUMN2NEWVALUE,
            NOW(),
            USER);
    END IF;
END;
```

but i have around 40 columns in table any other easey way  method to write columns name in loop and checking for value changes

Comment: What are the types of `OLD_VALUE` and `NEWVALUEW` columns in `ABN_OLDLOGTABLE`?

Comment: TYPE OF COLUMNS IS `VARCHAR(45)` for this am using `CONVERT`

Comment: I would suggest to create a similar 40 column table to record the new row each time an update is made, e.g. `TABLE working (a,b,c); TABLE update_history (a,b,c,time,op)`, so when the table updated, you `INSERT INTO update_history (new.a,new.b,new.c,now(),'update')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to write small utility that will read schema of given table from MySQL and create trigger that checks all the column.  They you need to rerun this utility once table structure is changed.  Let me know if you need help writing such utility.

Here is the script that generates triggers:

```
#!/bin/sh

db="$1";
shift

echo "DELIMITER ;;"
for table in "$@"
do
  sql="show columns from $table"
  columns=`mysql -B -N -e "$sql" "$db" | cut -f 1`
  echo "CREATE TRIGGER ${table}_log"
  echo "AFTER UPDATE ON $table"
  echo "FOR EACH ROW BEGIN"
  for column in $columns
  do
    echo "  IF (OLD.$column != NEW.$column) THEN"
    echo "    INSERT INTO ABN_OLDLOGTABLE (TABLENAME, COLUMNNAME, OLDVALUE, NEWVALUEW, TIME, USER)"
    echo "    VALUES (\"$table\", \"$column\", OLD.$column, NEW.$column, NOW(), USER());"
    echo "  END IF;"
  done
  echo "END;;"
done
```

Save it as `trigger.sh`, set executable bit on it (`chmod a+x trigger.sh`) and then run like this:

```
trigger.sh dbname table1 table2 ...
```

It will print triggers code on STDIN.

Comment: `set executable bit on it (chmod a+x trigger.sh)` no idea how could i do these am using mysqlworkbench

Comment: @eldhosevarghese Do this in shell, not in mysqlworkbench.  Are you working on Unix/Linux?

Comment: no idea about linux do you know how can i execute these in windows thanks

Comment: @eldhosevarghese You can install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) with MySQL client and invoke my script from cygwin console.  Also you may rewrite my script on your preferred programming language that you can run on Windows.